# How to change opacity with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to fade an element that is being created dynamically with JavaScript.

Here's a CSS example of what I am trying to do: https://codepen.io/deejay/pen/OJJqZaL

Javascript

```js
...
  const fadeOutWithOpacity = () => {
    const opacity = totalCount >= 1 && 0.5;
    return opacity;
  };

  const handleOpacity = () => {
    setInterval(() => {
      fadeOutWithOpacity();
    }, 3000);
  };

...
style: {
    background: "#FA4379",
    color: "#fff",
    opacity: `${handleOpacity()}`
  }
```

I only want to change the opacity value every 3sec

Comment: Why don't you want to use css to fade it?

Comment: @Deejay pure javascript or jQuery?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. The JavaScript you've provided here won't compile, and if it did there is no HTML for it to apply to.

Comment: @JulyanoFelipe — It *looks* like they are using some SPA framework (maybe React) which uses CSS-in-JS … but the question is massively lacking in detail.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fade in element by setting opacity with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25682379/fade-in-element-by-setting-opacity-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Javascript to add a class to your element which will cause the opacity to decrease slowly thanks to the CSS `transition` property.

```js
const spawnBox = () => {
  var box = document.createElement("div");
  box.className = "box";  
  
  box.onclick = (event) => {
    box.classList.add("hidden");
  };
  
  document.body.appendChild(box);
};

spawnBox();
setInterval(() => {
  spawnBox();
}, 1000);
```

```css
.box {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  
  margin: 5px;
  
  background: red;
  
  transition: opacity .5s;
}

.box.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}
```